# This site can’t be reached took too long to respond in cs-cart

Tags: amazon-ec2, cs-cart

Our site unfortunately goes to down error like this "This site can’t be reached  took too long to respond", please help me why this happen and our server run on docker container using AWS

[image]

Answer (score 0):

over 20 projects runing on https://zahid.host/ref/2864-6b7e-4af0
I think not enough RAM or proccesor.